# What should I do if I am unable to have a different amount of columns per table row?

Tags: mysql

Basically, I keep records of client information, and sometimes they will have multiple addresses (properties), e.g.:

id, name, phone, primaryProperty, **properties**

Considering I cannot create a random number of columns for each entry, I currently just grab the string value from a JavaScript array I create, which is used to hold all of the clients properties, e.g.:

```
['123 Fakestreet Faketown QC A1A1A1', '555 Falsestreet Falsetown QC B2B2B2']
```

then I convert it to a string, and then shove it into MySql

```
"123 Fakestreet Faketown QC A1A1A1, 555 Falsestreet Falsetown QC B2B2B2"
```

Unfortunately, as cool as arrays are, this makes it so that I can never properly query the above properties individually, unless I echo the value of the column out and use a for loop to change the contents around.

--

I realize that I could probably get away with increasing the total amount of columns on my clients table depending on the maximum amount of properties a client needs, but having a lot of unused fields for all of the other clients is a little strange, no?

I thought about creating a separate table for the properties, but then I would have a problem when it comes to updating the clients information efficiently, and without calling another update.php file. I have a fear of losing internet connection in between updating tables.... if that makes sense.

[image: Project Example]

Answer (score 0):

Normalization is an answer. Just split it into 2 tables. 1st one contains the unique data of the customer (name, shoe size etc.) and the ID. The 2nd table contains the same ID and addresses in the separate rows. Then you just join the tables on the ID column as you need.

Cheers!
G.